# Java started but returned exit code 13

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have tried doing some of the fixes online, like:
- making sure that I downloaded the correct version of Eclipse, 64 bit
- Eclipses supports Java 8, the one that I have installed
- reinstalled the IDE 3 times, but got the same problem

I am pretty big noob when it comes to these types of problems...

Here is a screen shot of the error:

[image]

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: @greg-449 thank you very very much! That was it. I had the 32 bit version of Java instead of the 64 bit. I guess I either downloaded the wrong one somehow or it was already installed...Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 1):

Add this line at the top of eclipse.ini

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin
```

Please check the name of folder you have in your system.

Comment: The '-vm' and the path **must** be on separate lines. This will only fix the problem if the JDK is 64 bit